# " rostopic list " error

Tags: ros, publish, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic list throws below error message:

```
 rostopic list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostopic", line 34, in <module>
    import rostopic
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 59, in <module>
    import rospy.impl.init
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/init.py", line 107, in <module>
    class RosStreamHandler(rosgraph.roslogging.RosStreamHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RosStreamHandler'
```

This error comes when I am executing this command on workstation computer. But when I run the same on turtlebot computer, it displays published topics.

Anyone please let me know what could be the issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61862/%22-rostopic-list-%22-error/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks very similar to [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/59644/rostopic-and-other-commands-fail-after-upgrade/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-04-30**:
Yeah, similar issue. The following packages have been kept back:
ros-groovy-rosgraph . So, installed this package. Thank you !! It resolved my problem.